# Code completion with static methods while using namespaces in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, php-5.3

This is a simplified version of [Netbeans PHP Code completion failing me, or am I failing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705125/netbeans-php-code-completion-failing-me-or-am-i-failing-it)

I have a namespace Sleek, inside this namespace there is class

```
<?php
namespace Sleek;
class Autoload {
   /**
    * Registeres our autoloader
    * @static
    * @return void
    */
   static public function register() {
      spl_autoload_register('\Sleek\Autoload::loader');
      ini_set('unserialize_callback_func', '\Sleek\Autoload::loader');
   }
}
```

However, when I attempt to use code-completion in Netbeans to view the available methods of the Autoload class via

```
\Sleek\Autoload::
```

It provides no suggestions, but the code works.

Is there any problem/fix I can do, or is it a issue with code completion and namespaces with static methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug with Netbeans code completion

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=206521